# Cooley-Tukey FFT algorithm for C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, signal-processing, fft

Has anyone created own library for Cooley-Tukey in C# for arbitrary-sized 1D samples?

I have found some free libraries but i need a compact piece of code for it without unnecessary code.

Although, I implemented this algorithm for 2^n - samples in a simple way and, of course, i have made a DFT method.

But can I generalize my code in a relatively simple way for arbitary-sized input array?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_ Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..